# BuildConfigField mock for unit test in Kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, buildconfiguration

I'm trying to cover as much as possible a **Kotlin Android library** and I'm encountering an issue about custom BuildConfig variable, better known as `buildConfigField`.

I would like to mock this variable to test both `true` and `false` values.

### Extract from Gradle file :

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_LOG", "false"
    }
    flavorDimensions "log"
    productFlavors {
        loggable {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_LOG", "true"
            dimension "log"
        }
        notloggable {
            dimension "log"
        }
    }
}
```

### Extract of the Kotlin function to be tested :

```
fun buildClient(): MyClient {
    var myClientBuilder : MyClient.Builder = MyClient.Builder();

    if (BuildConfig.ENABLE_LOG) {
        val interceptor = LoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(LoggingInterceptor.Level.ALL);
        myClientBuilder.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }

    return myClientBuilder.build()
}
```

### Unit test :

```
@Test
fun buildClient_enableLog_oneInterceptor() {
    // GIVEN
    Mockito.mock(BuildConfig::class.java)
    Mockito.doReturn(true).`when`(BuildConfig.ENABLE_LOG)

    // WHEN
    val myClient = myService!!.buildClient()

    // THEN
    assertNotNull(myClient)
    assertNotNull(myClient.interceptors())
    assertEquals(1, myClient.interceptors().size)
}
```

I tried different things and it never works.
If someone have already done this work, it can help me a lot (and others I guess).

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you send the variable `BuildConfig.ENABLE_LOG` as an argument to your function? That way you can mock it for testing by calling `buildClient(enableLog: Boolean)` ?

Or pull it to the class level by sending it in the constuctor of the class containing the function?

OR use dependency injection to inject the variable into your class?

Comment: I found a solution in the documentation : https://developer.android.com/studio/test/
You can check code at : https://github.com/BapNesS/android-unittests-demo

Comment: @BaptisteCarlier Can you please write that as an answer with some details? It's hard to follow the link to your code as there are a lot of other classes there that might need to check for the answer to this specific question. Just a simple snippet should do the job I think.

Comment: Plus both of his links not working  Seems to a spam comment

Answer (score 5):

```
ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(BuildConfig::class.java, "ENABLE_LOG", true)
```

Comment: From where can I import ReflectionHelpers?

Comment: "ReflectionHelpers" is part of the Robolectric eco system.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The config property doesn't change.

Comment: @ciaranodc - were you able to get this to work?

Comment: Its better to create a wrapper upon BuildConfig and get the value from that class you can mock it or inject anywhere .

Answer (score 0):

By default, all tests run against the debug build type. You can change this to another build type by using the testBuildType property in your module-level build.gradle file. For example, if you want to run your tests against your "staging" build type, edit the file as shown in the following snippet.

android {
...
testBuildType "staging"
}
but this is causing other options to fail

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party but this is how you should test any thing related to `BuildConfig` file.
`BuildConfig.java` is generated for each variant of your app. In your case you have atleast 4 variants.

1. LoggableDebug
2. LoggableRelease
3. NotloggableDebug
4. NotloggableRelease

`ENABLE_LOG` will be false for options 3 and 4.
If you want to Unit test this, I recommend writing UnitTest in `src/testNotLoggable/java/com/.../TestFile.java`.

In that `TestFile.java` your `BuildConfig.ENABLE_LOG` should be false.

You can check `BuildConfig.java` file for each variant under `/build/source/buildConfig/flavorname/debug/com/project/../BuildConfig.java`