# How to unit test the app behavior for different Gradle buildTypes in Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-type

I am trying to test the behavior of different stages in an Android app. Considering [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#build-types), I use different Gradle `BuildTypes` in the module's `build.gradle` to define the settings needed for each stage.

Each `buildType` block contains a String with a similar key `STAGE_NAME` and a different value for each stage for example `test_stage`, and `uat_stage`.

The value of those is being accessed in the app using `BuildConfig.STAGE_NAME` to change some of the parameters like API endpoints accordingly.

But the problem is, there seems to be no official way to unit test the resulting behavior for each stage.

The Android docs, mention a way to [change the test `buildType`](https://developer.android.com/studio/test#change_the_test_build_type) which explicitly defines which `buildType` is being used for testing, but I was wondering if there is another approach to test the resulting behaviors.

The module's build.gradle file:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            buildConfigField "String", "STAGE_NAME", "\"debugStage\""
            ...
        }
        testStage {
            initWith(debug)
            buildConfigField "String", "STAGE_NAME", "\"testStage\""
            ...
        }
        uatStage {
            initWith(debug)
            buildConfigField "String", "STAGE_NAME", "\"uatStage\""
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Example Retrofit interface which is supposed to use different API URLs for each stage by accessing the `STAGE_NAME` and find out which of the URLs should be used as `API_URL`:

```
interface FakeService {
    @GET("stuff")
    suspend fun getStuff(): List<Stuff>?

    ...
    
    companion object {

        // Different urls which should be used for each stage:
        private const val URL_DEBUG = "https://debug_api.example.com/"
        private const val URL_TEST = "https://test_api.example.com/
        private const val URL_UAT = "https://uat_api.example.com/"
        private const val URL_PROD = "https://prod_api.example.com/"

        // This is where we access the STAGE_NAME to figure out which stage url should be used
        val API_URL_TO_USE = getUrl(BuildConfig.STAGE_NAME)
        
        fun getUrl(stageName: String?): String {
            return when (stageName) {
                "debugStage" -> URL_DEBUG
                "testStage" -> URL_TEST
                "uatStage" -> URL_QA
                else -> URL_PROD
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example in this retrofit interface, I would like to test the behavior of `getUrl` function to make sure it returns the right URL for each stage.

**UPDATE:**
After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181057/buildconfigfield-mock-for-unit-test-in-kotlin), I was wondering maybe one way of testing this, could be mocking the `BuildConfig`. But since the `STAGE_NAME` is only available after a successful build, it can not be mocked normally.